# Emulating NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction with UIImage

Tags: iphone, macos, uiimage, porting, nsimage

I really need to emulate the behavior of NSImage's drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction using UIImage and I'm wondering what's the best approach or (better), if somebody already did this and willing to share the code.

I tried doing this using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect (see code at the end) but I'm not getting the expected results. Note that the code is actually testing this on the mac (I can't run the whole thing on the iPhone as of now) so I may have some issue with getting the CGImage from NSImage

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect fromRect:(CGRect)fromRect alpha:(float)alpha {
      CGContextRef context;
       CGImageRef originalImageRef;
       CGImageRef subimageRef;

#if ERMac
       context=[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

       CGImageSourceRef source;

       source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[self TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
       originalImageRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
       CFRelease(source);
#else
       context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
       originalImageRef=CGImageRetain([self CGImage]);
#endif

       subimageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect (originalImageRef, fromRect);


       CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, subimageRef);


       if (subimageRef)
           CGImageRelease(subimageRef);
       if (originalImageRef)
           CGImageRelease(originalImageRef);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it...

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)drawRect fromRect:(CGRect)fromRect operation:(CGBlendMode)blendMode fraction:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, drawRect);

    CGFloat xScale = (drawRect.size.width/fromRect.size.width);
    CGFloat yScale = (drawRect.size.height/fromRect.size.height);

    CGFloat scale = 1;
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    {
        scale = self.scale;
    }

    CGFloat actualWidth = (xScale * self.size.width)*scale;
    CGFloat actualHeight = (yScale * self.size.height)*scale;
    CGFloat xInset = fromRect.origin.x * xScale;
    CGFloat yInset = fromRect.origin.y * yScale;

    // Take care of Y-axis inversion problem by translating the context on the y axis
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, drawRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-xInset + drawRect.origin.x, -yInset + drawRect.origin.y, actualWidth, actualHeight), self.CGImage);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImage has drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:. A simple trick for extracting a subrectangle of a UIImage is to draw into a target context which is the size of the rectangle you want to extract, adjusting the origin of the drawn image up and to the left so that the right portion falls into the target context.

CGImage is also a good way to do this but you may encounter problems with the coordinate system being flipped on the iPhone. An easy solution is to wrap the CGImage into a UIImage and draw that, since UIImage knows which way up to draw.

Answer (score 0):

NSImage category method example and my port to iOS:

```
-(NSImage*)getSubimageWithRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                         initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                         pixelsWide:rect.size.width
                         pixelsHigh:rect.size.height
                         bitsPerSample:8
                         samplesPerPixel:4
                         hasAlpha:YES
                         isPlanar:NO
                         colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                         bytesPerRow:0
                         bitsPerPixel:0];

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep]];
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height) fromRect:rect operation:NSCompositingOperationCopy fraction:1.0];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rect.size];
    [newImage addRepresentation:rep];
    return newImage;
}
```

iOS code:

```
-(UIImage*)getSubimageWithRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height,
8, 4*width, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGImageRelease(ref);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return newImage;
}
```